# Using AngularJS factory to connect to google distance api using $resource

Tags: angularjs, api, distance, ngresource

I want to create a factory using $resource to retrieve distance information from google's distance api (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/).

I've stripped the parameters out to try and get the simple service working..

Here's my current code:

```
VenuesAppServices.factory('VenueDistance', ['$resource',
function($resource){
    return $resource('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json', {}, {
        Distance: {method:'GET'}
    });
}]);
```

and to call it:

```
VenueDistance.Distance(function(results){
    alert(JSON.stringify(results));
},function(error){
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

I would expect the following to be returned:

```
{
"destination_addresses" : [],
"error_message" : "The 'sensor' parameter specified in the request must be set to either 'true' or 'false'.",
"origin_addresses" : [],
"rows" : [],
"status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

However I get a 404 response.

```
{"data":"","status":404,"config":{"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"method":"GET","url":"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}}}
```

If you swap out the google api for one like (http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON). Then you get the expect response from that site.

Can anyone tell me why the google url is not returning the result you get from a browser?

Comment: it depends if google follows the convention angulars $resource expects

Comment: what is the actual get angular is sending out?

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not send parameters like origin and destinations..

You need to a URL send via $resource or $http service:

```
VenuesAppServices.factory('VenueDistance', ['$resource',function($resource){
return $resource('http://google.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Bobcaygeon+ON|41.43206,-81.38992&destinations=Darling+Harbour+NSW+Australia|24+Sussex+Drive+Ottawa+ON|Capitola+CA', {}, { Distance: {method:'GET'}});}]);
```

or

```
VenuesAppServices.factory('VenueDistance', ['$resource',function($resource){
return $resource('http://google.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins='+ origin +'&destinations='+ destination, {}, { Distance: {method:'GET'}});}]);
```

[Google Maps API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/)

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you are getting cross domain javscript http request error and stringifying it